# Mostrar nombre al iniciar sesion php

Tags: php, sesiones

quiero que cuando alguien se registre o inicie sesión, se muestre su nombre de usuario. Mi código es este

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 header-top-right">
                <div class="header-social">
                    <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=es"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                              
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container main-menu">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between d-flex">
          <div id="logo">
            <img class="favicon" src="../imagenes/favicon.png" alt="" title="" />
          </div>
          <nav id="nav-menu-container">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
              <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <?php

                if($_SESSION['usuariologin'] = null){
                    echo "<li><a href='registro.php' type='button'  class='primary-btn'>Registrate o Inicia Sesi&oacute;n</a></li>";
                }else{
                    echo $_SESSION['usuariologin'];
                }
              ?>

              <li><a href="eventos.php">Eventos</a></li>
              <li><a href="buscador.php">Buscador</a></li>
              <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Pages</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Level2 </a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>                                         
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container-->                               
        </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- #header -->
```

Pero cuando cargo la página no me muestra nada (el session_star está más arriba aqui no lo puse pero está). No se si es que lo veo más fácil de lo que es o que pero no entiendo por qué no funciona alguna idea?

Comment: Supongo que junto al session_start() le diste valor a $_SESSION['usuariologin'], ¿Es eso cierto o el valor se lo das en otro lado?

Comment: Si, lo coge de registro.php, cuando se registra lo guardaen $_SESSION['usuariologin] y cuando inica sesion lo mismo.

Comment: Mmmm, pues entonces, ¿Puede ser que los elementos estén ocultos por CSS? Quizás tus estilos hacen que en los nav-menu se oculte todo lo que no está entre etiquetas <li><a></a></li>. Deberías probar encerrar el nombre de usuario entre dichas etiquetas al igual que lo haces en el otro echo.

Comment: Vale voy a probar pero no creo porq tampoco me aparece el otro el que es solo etiquetas.

Comment: En el if estás haciendo una asignación (`=`) en lugar de una comparación (`==`), también sería preferible que que utilices isset(), ya que puede darse el caso de que la variable de sesión no esté definida.